# Bootstrap Radio Buttons and Links in Horizontal Rows

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I seem to be having an issue in Bootstrap when trying to add some custom radio buttons AND a hyperlink in the same row.  It looks like I can either have the hyperlink work OR have the data-toggle on so the radio buttons click; but not both, or at least can't have both with the standard col structure.  I'm assuming I'm doing something incorrectly, but cannot figure it out.

**Code where radio buttons work**; but for the hyper link you can hover (and see the correct URL), you can right click and open in new window (and that works), but clicking on the link doesn't do anything (stay on page, no action)

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row align-content-center">
                <div class="col text-center d-none d-md-block"><h4>Column One</h4></div>
                <div class="col text-center"><h4>Column Two</h4></div>
                <div class="col text-center"><h4>Column Three</h4></div>
                <div class="col text-center"><h4>Column Four</h4></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row align-content-center btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                <div class="col text-center d-none d-md-block"><h4>Column One</h4></div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" name="options" id="option1" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
                        Option One
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" name="options" id="option2" value="2" autocomplete="off" />
                        Option Two
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
                        <img src="~/img/home.png" alt="Home Page" title="Home Page" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row align-content-center btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                <div class="col text-center d-none d-md-block"><h4>Column One</h4></div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" name="options" id="option1" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
                        Option One
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" name="options" id="option2" value="2" autocomplete="off" />
                        Option Two
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
                        <img src="~/img/home.png" alt="Home Page" title="Home Page" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Code where hyper-link works**; but radio buttons don't "stay on" when clicked

```
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-content-center">
                <div class="col text-center d-none d-md-block"><h4>Column One</h4></div>
                <div class="col text-center"><h4>Column Two</h4></div>
                <div class="col text-center"><h4>Column Three</h4></div>
                <div class="col text-center"><h4>Column Four</h4></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row align-content-center">
                <div class="col text-center d-none d-md-block"><h4>Column One</h4></div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" name="options" id="option1" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
                        Option One
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" name="options" id="option2" value="2" autocomplete="off" />
                        Option Two
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
                        <img src="~/img/home.png" alt="Home Page" title="Home Page" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row align-content-center">
                <div class="col text-center d-none d-md-block"><h4>Column One</h4></div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" name="options" id="option1" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
                        Option One
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" name="options" id="option2" value="2" autocomplete="off" />
                        Option Two
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
                        <img src="~/img/home.png" alt="Home Page" title="Home Page" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

You can see the difference is in the div with the row with the "btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons"

The other method I've tried is to add a div with the data-toggle around just the radio buttons; this makes they hyperlink work but stacks the radio buttons / doesn't have the col layout desired.

Answer (score 0):

The property breaking the even distribution for the radio buttons in the earlier code is `display:inline-flex` which is part of the class `btn-group`, turn this to `display:flex` to get what you want...

working **snippet** below:

```css
.btn-group {
  display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-content-center">
    <div class="col text-center d-none d-md-block">
      <h4>Column One</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h4>Column Two</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h4>Column Three</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h4>Column Four</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-content-center btn-group btn-group-toggle myToggleClass" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="col text-center d-none d-md-block">
      <h4>Column One</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" name="options" id="option1" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
                        Option One
                    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" name="options" id="option2" value="2" autocomplete="off" />
                        Option Two
                    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
        <img src="~/img/home.png" alt="Home Page" title="Home Page" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-content-center btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="col text-center d-none d-md-block">
      <h4>Column One</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" name="options" id="option1" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
                        Option One
                    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden" name="options" id="option2" value="2" autocomplete="off" />
                        Option Two
                    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
        <img src="~/img/home.png" alt="Home Page" title="Home Page" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the option; but this looks like it has the same issue as the second example in the question (i.e. that the link doesn't work / isn't clickable) ... so it displays well; but since the link is in a div with data-toggle="buttons" the link doesn't work on click (if you right click and open in new window it works; and it displays link on hover; just isn't clickable and the data-toggle seems to be the issue) ... i need a row with radio buttons that are toggled; but that the link just works as expected